# I want to use amazon SQS to save the messages and use lambda to read the queue data and dump it into mysql

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am working with PHP technology.
I have my program that will write message to Amazon SQS.
Can anybody tell me how I can use lambda service to get data from SQS and push it into MySQL. Lambda service should get trigger whenever new record gets added to the queue.
Can somebody share the steps or code that will help me to get through with this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any official way to link SQS and Lambda at the moment. Have you looked into using an SNS topic instead of an SQS queue?

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Mark B.
Ways to get events over to lambda.

1. use SNS  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-lambda.html
2. use SNS->SQS and have the lambda launched by the sns notification just use it to load whatever is in te SQS queue.
3. use kinesis.
4. alternatively have lambda run by cron job to read sqs. Depends on needed latency.  If you require it be processed immediately then this is not the solution because you would be running the lambda all the time.

Important note for using SQS.  You are charged when you query even if no messages are waiting.  So do not do fast polls even in your lambdas.  Easy to run up a huge bill doing nothing.   Also good reason to make sure you set up cloudwatch on the account to monitor usage and charges.